# Wordpress Contact Form 7 file uploads

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have created a form that requires users to upload 2 photos.

```
<p>Photo 1<br />
[file your-file1 filetypes:jpg limit:10240kb]</p> 
<p>Photo 2<br />
[file your-file2 filetypes:jpg limit:10240kb]</p>
<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

I can receive both the photos through email but my server only stores the first photo.

My "Save Contact Form 7" table shows links to both photos submitted by the user but I can only open the first link. The second link opens 404.

Upon checking **/wp-content/uploads/nimble_uploads** the server, only the first photo is stored in the server.

My server:
upload_max_filesize is set to 30mb
post_max_size is set to 60mb

What else could be the problem? I don't see any error in the logs. What else should I check?

Thanks.

Comment: You might try some multiple file upload plugin for CF7 like this: https://hu.wordpress.org/plugins/multifile-upload-field-for-contact-form-7/

Comment: Have you added both of the files in the file attachment input on the admin page?

Comment: HI @Tasos. Attachment inputs are working.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem whereby Contact Form 7 was saving the files one by one, processing them, then deleting them, each time using the same file name/location, so that only the last file would show up. If you dig into the code in the cf7 plugin, under submissions.php there is some code like `$this->remove_uploaded_file` around line 180 which you need to comment out. You also need to append some random string on the end of the file name (but before the extension) so when subsequent files are uploaded they don't stomp (ie overwrite) any already uploaded.

Also take a look at the [flamingo plugin](https://contactform7.com/save-submitted-messages-with-flamingo/) (by the developer of cf7) which saves all the uploaded data's info in the wp-metadata table so you can retrieve it, although the above tweaks are still necessary as you wouldn't save images in a database.

Answer (score 0):

check the php.ini file and make sure that the post_max_size is set higher than your upload data and max_file_uploads is greater than 1.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. The max_file_uploads is currently 20. The photos are below 5mb each.

Only the first photo could get into the server. 
What else should I look out for?